# C++ как преобразовать заголовочные файлы для ассемблера?

Tags: c++, ассемблер, компиляция, рефлексия

Всем доброго времени суток,
опишу максимально конкретно, нужно из C++ .h файлов от Vulkan API выпотрошить структуры и привести их к ассемблерному виду.
То есть:

```cpp
public class Vector
{
     byte A = 1;
     float B = 2.0f;
     int C = 3;
}
```

сделать нечто вида

```
Vector:
   A db 1
   _allign db 0, 0, 0
   B dd 2.0
   C dd 2

;немного пояснений d(*) означает сохранить переменную в качестве данных, то есть сохранить в конечный PE-файл прям на диск.
; db = 1 байт, dw = 2, dd = 4 байта и т.д.
```

а если быть точнее, нужно просто узнать адреса и размеры полей

Соответственно зачем это нужно?
чтобы иметь готовые структуры выровненные как надо со всеми атрибутами и прочими особенностями заложенными программистами.

Насколько я понимаю нативная рефлексия вообще отсутствует, я даже не знаю куда копать, можно ли как-то перенастроить этапы компиляции или внешние библиотеки рефлексии могут помочь?

*и да я не программирую на c++, поэтому вопрос может показаться глупым))*

Comment: для линукса есть gdb. в нём можно просмотреть ассемблерный код программы после компиляции. с учетом оптимизаций или без них..

Comment: Ну во-первых в C++ фиксированная структура имеется только у standard layout типов. В противном случае вам придется подстраиваться под особенности сборки конкретным компилятором. Во-вторых, малопонятно для чего вы собираетесь их потом использовать. Просто дергать это API из ассемблера выглядит как глупая затея.

Comment: @VTT я бы сказал не столько нужен ассемблер, сколько именно бинарная реализация. Насколько я понимаю, раз апи публичный, то по идеи он использует вполне конкретный формат.